# I want to run PowerShell as admin AND execute a command in the admin power shell THROUGH Java

Tags: java, powershell, process, exec

I am working on a Java program which allows me to create a new local user on my PC. The only problem is that I have to execute my PowerShell command as admin.

When I run the file I put a name and a password. Then I click a button which starts PowerShell as admin.

## The Problem

The command which creates a new user is not executed in the PowerShell I started as admin.

```java
String command = "powershell.exe Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs ; New-LocalUser -Name " + str_name + " -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString " + str_pass + " -AsPlainText -Force)";
Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
String line;
System.out.println("Output:");
BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
stdout.close();
System.out.println("Error:");
BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
stderr.close();
System.out.println("Done");
```

## What happens

PowerShell is opening as admin but the actual command is executed in a normal PowerShell which prints this error: `access denied`

That's because I can only create a new local user as admin.

Why is my command is not executed in the PowerShell which is running as admin?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's parse the command to see what happens.

```
"powershell.exe Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs ; New-LocalUser -Name " 
  + str_name 
  + " -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString " + str_pass + " -AsPlainText -Force)";
```

Note the semicolon after `-Verb RunAs`.It's a statement separator, so `Start-Process` is going to be one statement and `New-LocalUser` is going to be another one. As pseudocode:

> Start powershell.exe. Process 1
>
> Start a new Powershell process as admin. Process 2
>
> Run New-LocalUser. Process 1

Note anything funny yet? The `New-LocalUser` is being run in the *original*, non-elevated Powershell session (Process 1). As it is not the one ran as Admin, you'll get an access denied error.

To run the user creation, its command needs to be passed to the elevated Powershell process, not to the parent. Use `-ArgumentList` to pass the commands to the elevated one like so,

```
powershell.exe Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList `
  'New-LocalUser -Name "TestUser" -Password `
  (ConvertTo-SecureString "H4rdT0Gue$$" -AsPlainText -Force)"'
```

Note the different quotes for `-ArgumentList` and `NewUser` parameters. When invoking nested Powershell sessions, take care to build the argument string in proper a way.